# Porting a game from Android SDK GLES 1.0 to NDK GLES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, porting

I'm currently developing an Android game using the SDK GLES10 and I'm experiencing some performace issues with it on not so good phones like the Samsung Galaxy Ace. So I've thought about porting it to the NDK and maybe also make it use GLES20, at least the rendering part which comsumes the most CPU time.

(on the Galaxy S2 it runs with constant 61 FPS, on the Galaxy Ace it varies between 90 and 20 FPS and is stuttering most of the time)

most CPU time consumnig methods on both Galaxy S2 and Galaxy Ace are `GLES10.glDrawElements()`, `GLES10.glVertexPointer()` and `GLES10.TexCoordPointer()`. like 85% of overall CPU time used on the Ace and 82% on the S2.

Would it drastically increase the performance to 1. use the NDK for rendering and 2. port it to GLES20?

Comment: Maybe you should profile your code first to see why it is slow. Also changing from GLES1 to GLES2 won't automatically yield any performance increase. If you do the same thing in GLES2 as GLES1 the perf will be the same.

Comment: I already did that, the rendering is the bottleneck as i also said in my question... and btw you can't "do the same thing in GLES20. it's very different to code for GLES20 than for GLES10

Comment: The lines of code may be different, but it's easy "to do the same thing". You have to write your own shader, but if your shader just emulates what the fixed function pipeline does, then the work that the GPU is doing will come out the same, unless you drastically change your rendering pipeline. If you run GLES1 code on a GLES2 compliant GPU it's probably already using shaders anyway behind the scenes.

Comment: and what about using the NDK, does it result in a performance gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really probably just depends on what you're already doing.

I'd look at finding **specific** bottlenecks. Saying that "rendering" is a bottleneck is way too vague to be useful.

What is holding you back exactly?

- SwapBuffers call time?
- too many OpenGL state changes?
- GPU vertex bound?
- GPU fill-rate bound?

Depending on the answer to this using NDK may help, or it may not help at all, depending on if your GPU is the limiting factor.

NDK might help you get calls to the GPU with less overhead, but you don't know if that's whats actually holding you back.

Try using the DDMS traceview if you haven't yet, and see where most of your time is going, then you can make an informed decision before you go through the trouble of a major rewrite.

Comment: most CPU time consumnig methods on both Galaxy S2 and Galaxy Ace are `GLES10.glDrawElements()`, `GLES10.glVertexPointer()` and `GLES10.TexCoordPointer()`. like 85% of overall CPU time used on the Ace and 82% on the S2 (also updated the question with these information)

Comment: @AndreasLinden: Using the NDK will probably help that some (opengl calls have more overhead in SDK), though it would probably be better if you can find some way to reduce the number of those calls. That seems like a really high percentage, what kinds of objects are you drawing? Is there any way you could combine some objects together?

Comment: hm, i'm mostly drawing rectanlges with indices and a few trianlges, both using GL_TRIANGLES. I've already optimized my maps to have as few as possible vertices.

Comment: @AndreasLinden If it's CPU bound, you should rather try to optimize them to have as few as possible objects (draw calls). E.g. by putting multiple objects together into a single `glDrawElements` call. Don't issue a `glDrawElements` for each individual rectangle or such things.

Comment: @ChristianRau how to pass multiple objects to `glDrawElements`?

Comment: @AndreasLinden That's not possible. That's why you need to batch them together into a single buffer manually.

Comment: @ChristianRau how does it nox mix up the different vertices then? do you have an example of this?

Comment: @AndreasLinden Imageine you have a rectangle consisting of 4 vertices drawn using `glDrawElements` using 6 indices (2 triangles). When drawing two of those you don't call `glDrawElements` two times, but only one time, using a vertex array that contains all 8 vertices and a index array with 12 indices (4 triangles). But of course you have to adapt the indices of the second rectangle to start at 6 instead of 0. And it may also interfere with other per-object state, as transformations or shaders. Batching doesn't just come at no extra cost.

Comment: @ChristianRau well, i use translatef on all objects, so i can't do this batching. also some objects are moving which would mean if i setup the vertices to be drawn without translatef i would have to recreate the vertices evertime something moves...